# visual studio 2012 c++ hello world - iostream not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have an issue with Visual Studio's 2012. I am also using "Sams Teach Yourself C++ in One Hour a day, 7th edition".

After using google to find the "best" compilers for C++, Visual Studios seemed to be the tool of choice.

So I downloaded and installed Visual Studios 2012. The very first lesson in the book is (and tells me to run it as a console app by going to **File > New > Project >Visual C++ > Win32 > Console Application** )

```
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
 std::cout << “Hello World!” << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

which doesnt work, at all. it outputs an error message similiar to the following:

> 1>c:\users\nik\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4.cpp(8):
>   error C2065: '“Hello' : undeclared identifier
>   1>  Generating Code...
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="

(there is more lines similiar to the first, but its rather long)

However, after googling and watching a video on youtube the following code works (using **File > New > Project >Visual C++ > General > Empty Project** )

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Hello Nik" << endl;
_getch();

return 0;
}
```

Does Visual Studio's 2012 have a C++ compiler? or does it just have a visual c++ compiler (if thats even the issue, only reason I think it could be is I can see templates for Visual C++ but none for c++ by itself...) or do I need to download Visual Studio Express to download native c++ ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am feeling some-what out of my depth here...

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong apostrophes? “” instead of ""

Comment: Visual Studio is not compiler, it's just "big text editor" for any compiler.

Comment: To post this question I copy pasted the code as it was written in the book, so I think thats why the apostrophes where different. Tried anyway and still get a failed error.

Comment: @Kamil - even the free "express" version includes compilers, and plenty more tools. "Visual Studio" is the name for the whole package.

Comment: I just pointed, that Visual Studio is not a compiler (sorry for bad english).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides aphostrophes **you may need to disable precompiler headers in project properties.**

They are turned on by default in VS2012. If you are not familiar with precompiled headers turn them off.

1. Right click on project (not solution)
2. Click properties.
3. Expand "Configuration properties"
4. Expand "C/C++"
5. Choose "Precompiled headers"
6. Set "Precompiled header" to "Not Using Precompiled Headers"

[More information about precompiled headers and stdafx.h file at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h)

Comment: I couldn't find the pre configured headers the way you described. However I started a new project and unchecked the tickbox for pre compiled headers and it worked properly! Thanks so much

Comment: I skipped "Click properties" on my "list". I fixed my answer now.

Comment: Interesting, I had precompiled headers on and still was able to reproduce the same error as in the question (given the apostrophes were wrong.) Something else must be going on here. I don't seriously believe the precompiled headers are the culprit.

Comment: Alex R. if you have precompiled headers turned on - compiler is skipping not precompiled "iostream" and looking for stdafx.h when you are using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 7):

The apostrophes you used are wrong:

```
“Hello World!”
```

should be

```
"Hello World!"
```

Notice even how SO recognizes the difference. You should at least type the code you see in the book instead of copying and pasting it. ;-)

Comment: I did. I was simply copy pasting what was written on the book for the purpose of this question as I had the other code on the page.

Comment: Then why copy the one from the book instead of the one you _are_ actually using in your app for the purposes of this question? I tried your actual code in my IDE--lo and behold I got the same undeclared identifier error. Hence, just try changing the apostrophes and you should be fine.

Comment: I probably should have control - z to get back to my original code rather then copy pasting from the book, however, I did originally use the proper apostrophes. Thanks for the answer though. Oh, and the down vote didn't come from me. Thanks again

Comment: @Nik You can always copy your _actual_ code--minus the irrelevant parts--and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The Win32 console application is actually quite different from the empty project. Win32 utilize a message (input) queue which you poll in a loop and your program respectively utilizes the Win32 API and performs certain operations.

The empty project is a bit less dependent on Win32 or anything that Windows provides in terms of API unless you make it dependent on it. This would be the simples hello world app in you empty project:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just try this::

**"Hello World!"** instead of **“Hello World!”**.

Comment: Who is voting down our answers? Whoever it is please explain as it is rightful to do so.

Comment: @AlexR.- And why you are asking me? I am the one whose answer have got down vote. Would you please explain?

Comment: No, in fact I upvoted you. And I am not asking you. Whoever downvoted your answer also downvoted mine, I guess. But he/she did not care to explain why, which is irresponsible.

Comment: +1 for that then. We pointed out the very obvious error seen in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your error you have to delete std:: of std::cout and std::endl, and write using namespace std; underneath #include iostream and and change “ ”  with " ".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
   cout <<"Hello World" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

In Visual studio 2012

```
 file>new projet>visual c++ (Project win32)>application settings(application console+Not Using Precompiled)>in right box in you Project (right click, add>new element>file c++).
```

Comment: what changes did you make at all? Did you explain anything at all? Unhelpful answer =(

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
“Hello World!” and 
"Hello Nik" is the apostrophe.
```

Aslo is the error persists than just check visual c++ library linker.

There is aslo definitely no need for conio.h

If your going to copy from a book at least copy it correctly.

```
Using namespace std; 
would be pretty smart in this case.
```